# How to trigger sns for a dms serverless task status changed to failed state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-serverless, aws-dms

As the title describes my issue, I want to know if there is any way to configure an AWS DMS serverless task to AWS SNS.